# import local packages inside PyFlink

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I'm trying to write a local package in PyFlink project.
But I can only import via relative path.

like

```
from .package import func
```

Can I use absolute paths in packages inside PyFlink project imported as   `env.add_python_file('/path_to_project')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using absolute paths answer from https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@flink.apache.org:
full answer [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread/93hcdcvxwlxx7lzj8sfq4d4k6pq4tp6n)
for abstract structure the directory:

```
flink_app/
    data_service/
        filesystem.py
    validator/
        validator.py
    common/
        constants.py
    main.py <- entry job
```

When submitting the PyFlink job you can specify python files  and entry main module with option --pyFiles and --pyModule[1](https://lists.apache.org/thread/93hcdcvxwlxx7lzj8sfq4d4k6pq4tp6n), like:

$ ./bin/flink run --pyModule flink_app.main --pyFiles ${WORKSPACE}/flink_app

In this way, all files under the directory will be added to the PYTHONPAHT of both the local client and the remote python UDF worker.